# What is the relation between CAP_NET_RAW and net.ipv4.ping_group_range?

Tags: linux, ping, container, capabilities

I am using rootless containers, according to the buildah docs,

> Moreover, **pinging from a rootless container does not work because it lacks the `CAP_NET_RAW` security capability that the ping command requires.** If you want to ping from within a rootless container, you can allow users to send ICMP packets using this `sysctl` command:
>
> ```
> # sysctl -w "net.ipv4.ping_group_range=0 2000000"
> ```
>
> This action would allow any process within these groups to send ping packets.

I ran that sysctl command, and I checked the permissions on the container it says,

```
Current IAB: ... !cap_net_raw ...
```

So if you set `net.ipv4.ping_group_range` you do **NOT** need this capability? How are these two related?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There’s no direct relationship. `CAP_NET_RAW` is a [capability](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html) which allows the use of raw and packet sockets, and binding to any address for transparent proxying. `ping_group_range` is a `sysctl` [defining a group range](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/icmp.7.html) allowed to open ICMP echo sockets.

Both of these can be used to allow `ping` to send and receive ICMP echo packets, but they’re not a superset or subset of each other.